# NHibernate: Avoid N+1 Issues when base class is used in Mapping

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have the following scenario:

`Session` class has many `ProcessableItem`s and a `SqlTask` is derived from `ProcessableItem` class.
A `SqlTask` can have many variables (property `SqlTaskInputParameters`, `SqlParameterVariable` class; some tasks don't have variables).

The point is in the `Session` class the `ProcessableItem` (not the task itself) is used as navigation property:

```
public class Session 
{
    [DataMember]
    public virtual IList<ProcessableItem> ProcessableItems
    {
        get { return this._items; }
        set { this._items = value; }
    }       
}

public SessionMap()
{
    HasMany(t => t.ProcessableItems)
}

public class ProcessableItem
{
    ...
}

public class SqlTask : ProcessableItem
{
    [DataMember]
    public virtual IList<SqlParameterVariable> SqlTaskInputParameters { get; set; };
}
```

So in this scenario the base class `ProcessableItem` is used as navigation property and I want to eager load the variable objects of `SqlTask` in order to avoid the n+1 problem.

This is the code that I have, but how can I access specific properties of the derived `SqlTask` (like `SqlTaskInputParameters`):

```
var query = session.Query<ETLSession>()
                   .Where(s => s.Id == request.IdETLSession);
query.FetchMany(s => s.ProcessableItems)
                .ThenFetch(p => p.ChildsOnSuccess).ToFuture();
Session session = query.ToFuture().ToList().First();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not eager load relationships of derived class.

In your case you should not even, because you seems to be already fetching another collection (`ChildsOnSuccess`), and fetching an additional one here would cause a Cartesian product between them, causing your results to be duplicated. (This is a NHibernate limitation.)

The good news is, there are other ways than eager fetching for solving the N+1 issue.

- Keep lazy loading but enable [batching of lazy loads](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/performance.html#performance-fetching-batch). I have put some detailed explanation [here on Stack Overflow](/a/36070727/1178314).
- Use [second level cache](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/performance.html#performance-cache). But well, that is caching, so better start with the other one, which will anyway still be beneficial if you add second level cache later.